# Activating BJT with an isolated current source

Tags: bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvn0LB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit represents a very elementary variation of a BJT as an inverter amplifier, where ON/OFF is the input and Vo is the inverse amplified output. However, the presence of Q1 means the grounds of the two batteries are not directly tied together.

Based on my understanding of the behavior of a BJT, it shouldn't matter that the two batteries are pseudo-isolated like this. But I'm not 100% confident it doesn't make some difference. What I keep getting tripped up on is the B-E current flow doesn't return to the same ground as the C-E current flow. Does that actually matter in this circuit?

For context: BAT1 and Q1 are part of a black box device I need to interface with. The device was originally designed to energize an external burn wire, so it just needed to provide a lot of current for a short period of time. Only the + side of the battery and the collector of Q1 are exposed as connection points outside of the device. For my project, there's no burn wire, but I need to detect when the device *would* have energized the burn wire. I plan to use an optoisolator in my real hardware, so this question is purely academic.

Comment: Where's the ground of the input signal connected to? If it's not the emitter of the BJT, it's not going to do anything.

Comment: Assume the ON/OFF signal is grounded to BAT1

Comment: Should work fine, then; I don't see what the point of hooking it up like this is but I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Hearth. See the "For context" part of my question for a description of why I'm hooking it up like this.

Comment: @DanLaks What exactly do you need to do to "detect?" What will be the indicator or output transducer that you will want to drive? It's really easy to detect if an open collector output is open or grounded. What matters it what you plan to do with the detection. If you don't care to tell us, then I'd just say put a resistor and LED in series with the (+) and collector output. If the LED is on, you've detected the fact. So obviously, since I know you already know this, you want something else you haven't discussed yet. So what is it?

Comment: @jonk nothing secret, just didn't figure it was relevant to the question. There's an MCU powered by BAT2 that would read Vo as a digital input. What I do with Vo is out of context of my question though. The point of the question is whether a BJT can be used by two different sources that don't share the same ground.

Comment: @DanLaks So it's just to be turned into a usable, solid digital input that can be easily read and, possibly, is opto-isolated but not necessarily so? What's the (+) battery voltage with respect to the actively pulled-down collector? And what's the stated current compliance for the active pull-down (collector?)

Comment: @jonk again, not sure how that's relevant. As I stated in my question, I'm not actually using this circuit in my actual design. This is a purely academic question based on the principles of how BJT's work, not a hardware design question.

Comment: @DanLaks Assuming Q1 doesn't leak much when off, then when Q1 becomes active it pulls the MCU ground close to the (-) rail of the black box. That creates a solid galvanic connection allowing recombination current in the base of Q2 and thereby allowing Q2 emitter/collector current. It's not how I'd approach it. I worry about details which may make this somewhat less reliable. But you have your academic answer.